# RegEx replacement: how to get length of the match dynamically in replacement

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there a way to replace matching expression with the same length of characters found in the match? Easier to understand in code below:

```
var input = "hello hellspawn, goto hell!";
var pattern = @"(hell)(?!o)";
var replacement = "****"; // is there a dynamic way to specify length here?
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I can do it with matches:

```
var sbInput = new StringBuilder(input);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
   sb.Length = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < match.Length; i++) {
      sb.Append("*");
    }

    sbInput.Replace(match.Value, sb.ToString(), match.Index, match.Length);
}

var replaced = sbInput.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
    m => new string('*', m.Length),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```